# Get raw date time in doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Doctrine maps `datetime` fields in db to PHP `\DateTime` class. For some indexing requirements i need raw values of that fields. Iterating over result set and converting all `\DateTime` classes to text with `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`is not feasible. There must be some way to disable auto-converting for datetime fields.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to change the column definition to string in your doctrine entity ? A bit hacky but could work. Sorry, can't test right now.

Comment: @BenjaminDubois of course it works but after a `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update` command Doctrine converts field to string and mysql treat it like varchar. so, after that no `createdAt >= '2015-12-12'`.

Comment: Don't use this tool : you can't rollback when bad things happen. On my SF2 projects, I use phinx to control DB migrations.

Comment: I'm pretty much happy with doctrine console commands for years and i don't think not using it will work as an answer for my question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my answer was a bit too fast. I meant that changing the tool might help you keeping the date as datetime in mysql and treating it like a string in doctrine, but I failed with my explanation and it doesn't solve the comparison  problem. Maybe using raw results for the specific indexing request(s) ? Doctrine seems to keep datetime objects even when hydrating results to array.

Comment: have you think about redundant data? You can add a new column with the string type with the performing index policy (and query for it in the related scenario).

Comment: @Matteo i thought that. If i can't find any other way i will do that.

Comment: Can you give an example of what "indexing requirements" are?  I have used datetime for quite some time now and never had this sort of issue come up.

Comment: @Cerad we will send result to elastic search with all joined tables hydrated as array.